# Disabling authentication using Websphere MQ Explorer

Tags: ssl, jms, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq

We have a .NET application which reads from Websphere MQ.
The queue is local, and is managed using MQ Explorer.
The queue is authenticated using SSL certificates.

We would like to read from the same queue from an application being written in Java. I understand that in order to access the queue using JMS, we would need to regenerate the certificates specifically for use with Java. However, we have not yet been able to do this.

In order to continue with development and testing, is there a way, using MQ Explorer, to disable authentication on the queue or queue manager?

I am assuming that we can access the existing queue using JMS, and do not have to setup a new queue under 'JMS Administered Objects'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not the queue that is TLS/SSL enabled. It's the connection (i.e. channel) to the queue manager that is TLS/SSL enabled. You can create another channel that is not TLS/SSL enabled and connect to the queue manager to get messages from that queue.

Comment: From MQ Explorer it appears that there is only one channel setup, and that there is no SSL authentication for that channel - it states "No message security - SSL is not used for messages sent from this channel definition".

Comment: You need to really check your queue manager configuration and also .NET application which you mention uses SSL. If there is a non SSL Server Connection (SVRCONN) channel available, use it in your Java application